# Convert model collection to json_encode

Tags: magento2, collection, model, performance, json

Currently I'm converting my collection data to **`json_encode`** like this:

```
$collections = $this->modelFactory->create()->getCollection()
                   ->addFieldToFilter('status','1');
$result = array();
foreach($collections as $collection){
  $result[] = $collection->getData();
}
return json_encode($result);
```

The problem is I need to loop for each collection to get the array data so that I can put it inside **`json_encode`** function, is there a way I can convert the collection result to **`json_encode`** without looping?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$result = $collections->toArray();

return json_encode($result);
```

or

```
$result = $collections->getData();
return json_encode($result);
```